# Need to pass data into JavaScript forEach function

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to cycle through a JSON object and return a value based on what I'm looking for. Say the object contains people, each person has a name and a zipcode. I want a function that will return a zipcode when I pass a name to it.

The following code is giving me an 'undefined' error, so it must be something to do with scope.

```
var myArray=[
    {
        "name":"Joe",
        "zip":90210
    },
    {
        "name":"Bill",
        "zip":94109
    }
];

function findIt(myArray,target) {
    myArray.forEach(function (person) {
        if (person.name === target) {
            return person.zip;
        }
    });
}
var zip=findIt(myArray,"Joe");
```

Comment: That's not JSON. There's no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is always a string. Always. What you have is an array of objects.

Comment: your findIt function does not return anything, hence undefined as a result

Comment: Use `filter` (or `find` if you are using ES6) instead of `forEach`.

Comment: Note you can use `array.find` even if you are using ES5. Also `find` has some compatibility issues. So do check it before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning zip code from anonymous inner function and not from `findIt` function.

To solve this problem, you can store result from anonymous inner function in a variable and then return that variable from `findIt` function as demonstrated below.

```js
var myArray=[
    {
        "name":"Joe",
        "zip":90210
    },
    {
        "name":"Bill",
        "zip":94109
    }
];

function findIt(myArray,target) {
    var answer;
    myArray.forEach(function (person) {
        if (person.name === target) {
            answer = person.zip;
        }
    });
  
    return answer;
}
var zip=findIt(myArray,"Joe");
console.log(zip);
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot. The other answers are informative and I will look at them in more detail, but this is the simplest solution. Thank you!

Comment: @EamonnGormley `forEach` is the wrong thing to use for lookup in a data structure. `forEach` will iterate through the entire array no matter how quickly a match is found. See my answer for a much better solution.

Comment: Also if the same name appears more than once in the data, the last match will always be returned. I would consider that behaviour a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You're not `return`ing anything from your function

```
function findIt(myArray,target) { // <--------------------┐
    myArray.forEach(function (person) {          // <--┐  |
        if (person.name === target) {            //    |  |
            return person.zip; // returns this func ---┘  |
        }                                        //       |
    });                                          //       |
    // you need a return for this function  --------------┘
}
```

Anyway, even if you fix that, your function could still use a bit of work. `forEach` is going to loop through the entire set of data, even if it finds a match on the first item. `forEach` is the wrong thing to use here.

---

A really simple thing you could use is `Array.prototype.find`. `Array.prototype.find` will stop iterating through the data as soon as the first match is found.

```js
var myArray=[
  {
    "name":"Joe",
    "zip":90210
  },
  {
    "name":"Bill",
    "zip":94109
  }
]

const findIt = (data, target) => {
  // use Array.prototype.find
  let {zip} = myArray.find(({name})=> name === target) || {}
  return zip
}

console.log(findIt(myArray, 'Joe'))
// => 90210

console.log(findIt(myArray, 'unmatched name'))
// => undefined
```

But if you would rather implement the function yourself as a learning exercise, that would look like this. Note this code will operate like `Array.prototype.find` in that it will return as soon as the first match is found.

```js
var myArray=[
  {
    "name":"Joe",
    "zip":90210
  },
  {
    "name":"Bill",
    "zip":94109
  }
]

// implement generic find
const find = f => ([x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return undefined
  else if (f(x))
    return x
  else
    return find (f) (xs)
}

// implement your function using find
const findIt = (data, target) => {
  let {zip} = find (({name})=> name === target) (data) || {}
  return zip
}

console.log(findIt(myArray, 'Joe'))
// => 90210

console.log(findIt(myArray, 'unmatched name'))
// => undefined
```

This is a smarter way to write `findIt` because instead of concerning itself with looping through the list of data, or returning a matching object, it just calls a generic function (`find`) which can be reutilized by many other functions.

---

**ES5**

As a courtesy, I'm providing a pre-ES6 version of the code above

```js
var myArray=[
  {
    "name":"Joe",
    "zip":90210
  },
  {
    "name":"Bill",
    "zip":94109
  }
]

// implement generic find
function find (f) {
  return function(xs) {
    if (xs[0] === undefined)
      return undefined
    else if (f(xs[0]))
      return xs[0]
    else
      return find (f) (xs.slice(1))
  }
}

// implement your function using find     
function findIt (data, target) {
  var p = find (function(x) { return x.name === target }) (data) || {}
  return p.zip
}

console.log(findIt(myArray, 'Joe'))
// => 90210

console.log(findIt(myArray, 'unmatched name'))
// => undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

A callback version, just for fun:

```
function findIt(myArray,target, cb) {
    myArray.forEach(function (person) {
            if (person.name == target) cb(person.zip)
    });
}
```

Like:

```
findIt(myArray,"Joe", function(zip){ alert(zip) });
```

Update:

An example of finding and using one zip value at a time with the following array.

```
var myArray=[
    {
        "name":"Joe",
        "zip":90210
    },
    {
        "name":"Bill",
        "zip":94109
    },
    {
        "name":"Joe",
        "zip":12345
    }
];
```

It should now alert twice once for "90210" and a second time for "12345"

Comment: can you provide the use case for the continuation (callback) for this purely synchronous code ? other than "just for fun" i mean...

Comment: @naomik sure let me give an example

Comment: oh, nicely done. I hadn't considered matching more than one item as a valid answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is implemented like the fallowing, it dose not return a valid value (undefined).

```
forEach(array, callback) {
    for (var index in array) {
        callback(array[index]);
    }
}
```

you want to return the desired value once find it, so try this:

```
function findIt(myArray,target) {
    for (var index in myArray) {
        if (myArray[index].name === target) {
            return myArray[index].zip;
        }
    }

}
```

if the array have lots of items, this example will stop after find the one matched, rather than scan all items.